# OpenSSL cryptolib AES 256 CTR decryption returns randomly appearing different plaintext in C

Tags: c++, c, encryption, openssl, aes

I am currently trying to decrypt a message encrypted in AES_256_CTR using the OpenSSL C library.

Somehow my code behaves unwanted, and the resulting plaintext is first wrong, but also, after every execution of my code, something else. I checked the IV, the key, and the ciphertext, and all of them are the same for every execution. So how could it be that the resulting plaintext changes?

What could I do to fix this behavior, or does someone know what the problem could be here?

If I create a simple demo encryption and decryption, it works fine, so I guess the failure is not inside the `AES_256_CTR_decrypt` function.

Code of the decryption method:

```c
int AES_256_CTR_decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertextSize, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintextBuffer)
{    
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    int len = 0;

    int plaintextLen;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
            handleErrors();
        
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_ctr(), NULL, key, iv)) 
        handleErrors();
    
    // Disable padding, the total amount of data encrypted or decrypted must then be a multiple of the block size or an error will occur.
    if(1 != EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0))
        handleErrors();
    
                                 // this buffer "plaintextBuffer" is filled with radomly appearing stuff, for every call.
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintextBuffer, &len, ciphertext, ciphertextSize)) /* Failed to decrypt plaintext. */
        handleErrors();
    plaintextLen = len;
   
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintextBuffer + len, &len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintextLen += len;
   
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return plaintextLen;
}
```

Code of the calling function:

```
string Verifier::decryptLog(KEY_TYPE key, XOR_TYPE encLogMessage)
{
    array<unsigned char, IV_SIZE> iv;
    array<unsigned char, MESSAGE_LEN> ciphertext;
    unsigned char *logm = new unsigned char [MESSAGE_LEN]{0};
    array<unsigned char, MAC_LEN> mac, referenceMAC;
    size_t macLen, len;
    
    
    copy_n(encLogMessage.begin(), IV_SIZE, iv.begin());
    copy_n(encLogMessage.begin() + IV_SIZE, MESSAGE_LEN, ciphertext.begin());
    copy_n(encLogMessage.begin() + IV_SIZE + MESSAGE_LEN, MAC_LEN, mac.begin());
    
    
    CMAC(key.data(), ciphertext.data(), MESSAGE_LEN, referenceMAC.data(), &macLen, MAC_LEN);
    
    if (macLen != MAC_LEN) {
        cerr << "ERROR: Creating MAC failed." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    if (mac != referenceMAC){
        cerr << "Invalid MAC detected: ..." << endl;
        return "";
    }
    
    if (MESSAGE_LEN != (len = AES_256_CTR_decrypt
                        (ciphertext.data(), MESSAGE_LEN, key.data(), iv.data(), logm))) {
        cerr << "ERROR: Log encryption failed." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Return log.
    std::string s(logm, logm+MESSAGE_LEN);
    delete[] logm;
    return s;
}
```

I guess something with my memory allocation is wrong…?

The code runs in XCode, I use openssl@3.1.2 installed via Homebrew.

Ciphertext:

```
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
```

IV:

```
28 7E AB E4 7C 71 C2 2E 36 1C 1E 8D
```

Key:

```
DA D6 35 43 F3 13 1A 32 2E A2 49 A7 5B 81 2D C6 84 D9 6E B3 84 DF FC 56 C4 DF 33 CA 76 88 E6 2C
```

---

Edit:

The issue was that my IV was only 12 bytes long, but 16 are required. So 4 bytes were read out of boundaries, which lead to the “random” appearance of the plaintext.

Comment: Why is your IV only 12 bytes long? I would expect 16 bytes for `EVP_aes_256_ctr()`, s. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57486687/9014097).

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/crypto/comments/30x5xg/comment/cpx0nvl/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button

Check out RFC also : https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3686.txt

How are you getting the IV value?

Comment: `EVP_DecryptInit_ex()` requires a 16 bytes IV, so that with a 12 bytes IV the following unitinitialized 4 bytes lead to the plaintext changing with each decryption.

Comment: I don't understand:  your title says C language but you tagged as C++.  Are you mixing the languages?  I highly recommend not mixing them.  For example, in C++, there is function overloading, inheritance, and exceptions, which make interfacing with C more difficult.  If you are not mixing, then remove the C++ tag.

Comment: @Topaco are sure that this is also true for counter?

Comment: Pretty sure (as far as anyone can be without explicit testing). You should take a look at the link in my last comment. Maybe your encrypting side uses a concatenation of 12 bytes nonce and 4 bytes counter for the IV (similar like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR))) and you think you only need to specify the nonce reagarding `EVP_aes_256_ctr()`. This is not true, you need to specify the entire IV.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews OpenSSL only provides a C interface, but OP's code is C++.  Thus both C and C++ tags are appropriate here as both languages are involved.

Comment: @Topaco I will do! This will also explain, the different outputs because of an out-of-bounds read.

Comment: @Genfood [NIST SP 800-38A, Appendix F5](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/legacy/sp/nistspecialpublication800-38a.pdf) provides sample AES/CTR keys, initialization vector, plaintext, and ciphertext data.  The IVs are all 16 bytes.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Parts of the software are written in C and the verification part is written in C++. All the crypto code is in a shared library written in C. So it is a mixture of both languages.
And as mentioned, there is no “C++” Interface for OpenSSL, but you are right, I could have used the OpenSSL code directly with C++.

Comment: @Genfood Note that you can not safely reuse any key/IV combination with AES/CTR.

Comment: Make `logm` a `std::vector<char>`. I could spot one memory leak at a glance. You did return without deleting  `logm`.

Comment: @Topaco Thanks guys, that was the bug in here, and a bad one too! I wasted a whole day on it…
The idea behind the 12 bytes was that the last 4 bytes are used as “the counter”. Something like: IV || CTR. But I guess it doesn't matter at all, and we can count starting from the IV value. Nevertheless, I should have used 16 bytes for this too.

Comment: @Red.Wave the messages are of fixed size, 1024 bytes, and will be padded accordingly.

Comment: In mixed C/C++ environments, design the code on C++ basis, and use its safty measures; then provide a thin C wrapper API around it with `extern "C"` functions that forward everything to C++. You'll get far less bugs at runtime.

Comment: If messages are the same size, then why did you `new` the `logm`? Either make it a`vector` or a `unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>` (if size is constant but large), otherwise `array`. Why did you use a pointer for it?

Comment: @Red.Wave this was due to debugging, eventually, I tried random things. I will use a std::array again now that it is working again. :D

Comment: Don't try raw pointers! All they do is add more points of failure to your code; beginning with one bug, you'll end up with 10.